# Nodejs give callback with in the callback function

Tags: node.js

I want to do something like that:

```
callbackfunc=function(client, id, callback){
    callbackfunc2({'id': id}, myfunc);
}

var myfunc = function(err,result){
     callback(new Error("Ein Fehler"));
}


callbackfunc(client, 38373,function(err, data){
            console.log("Here:"+data+" Error:"+err);
});
```

How can I make the callback available in myfunc? I always get callback is not a function. If I write it his way it works. And I don't understand why it doesn't work when I had a special function.

```
callbackfunc=function(client, id, callback){
    callbackfunc2({'id': id}, function(err,result){
     callback(new Error("Ein Fehler"));
});

callbackfunc(client, 38373,function(err, data){
            console.log("Here:"+data+" Error:"+err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `callback` available in a separate function, then you have to either:

1. Pass it to `myfunc` as an argument.

or

2. Declare `myfunc` inside the scope where `callback` is available.

It works in this example:

```
callbackfunc=function(client, id, callback){
    callbackfunc2({'id': id}, function(err,result){
     callback(new Error("Ein Fehler"));
});
```

because you are calling `callback` from within the scope in which it is defined.  Remember function arguments are only available within the block of the function in which they are defined.  They are not available outside that function unless you pass them to some other scope as an argument or assign them to some other variable that is itself available in a different scope.

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer. So did I understand this right, I cannot pass callback to myfunc in the first example. The preferred way ist the second one which works fine.

Comment: @baeckerman83 - You can pass the callback to `myfunc`, but you have to  edit the function that ends up calling `myfunc` to do so which would be `callbackfunc2` in your first code block.  So, if you pass `callback` to `callbackfunc2` along with `myfunc`, then when that function calls `myfunc` is could also pass `callback` as an argument.